# Error running MapServer export in Quantum GIS

Tags: qgis, mapserver

I have a project in Quantum GIS that I need to export to a .map file using the plugin MapServer export.  I fill all the forms but I get this error when running the app.  Any ideas of what is happening?

Here is a copy of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\mapserver_export\mapserverexport.py", line 132, in ok_clicked
    self.saveMapFile()   File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\mapserver_export\mapserverexport.py", line 148, in saveMapFile
    print "Creating exporter using '%s' and '%s'" % (self.dlg.ui.txtQgisFilePath.text(), self.dlg.ui.txtMapFilePath.text()) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)

Versión de Python:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


Versión de QGIS:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Ruta de Python: ['C:/Users/SergioVM/.qgis//python/plugins\\sextante', 'C:\\Users\\SergioVM\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\elevation', 'C:\\Users\\SergioVM\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\cswclient', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/SergioVM/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/SergioVM/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', '~/.qgis/python', 'C:\\Users\\SergioVM\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\openlayersov\\logic', 'C:\\Users\\SergioVM\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\openlayersov\\gui', '/usr/share/qgis/python', 'C:\\Users\\SergioVM\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\QuickMultiAttributeEdit/forms', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:/SIG-SIXAOLA/Cartograf\xc3\xada/base_datos_final/Quantum_GIS_BD']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 49: ordinal not in range(128)
```

tells us that there are some special characters which cannot be handled.